# Origin of the similarity of "god" and "good"

Tags: etymology

In all the Germanic languages the words "god" and "good" are homomorphic - they sound almost identical: God and goed in Dutch, Gott and gut in German, guð and gott in Icelandic, Gud and god  in Norwegian, and, finally, Gud and god or gott in Swedish. What is the Proto-IndoEuropean root of this word, and where do we see it in other languages?

Comment: Welcome to the site! A good first stop for etymology questions is the Online Etymology Dictionary. Here are its entries on ["god"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=god&allowed_in_frame=0) and ["good"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=good&allowed_in_frame=0). You should edit your question based on what you learn from these (if these entries completely answer your question, it's a candidate for closure as "Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)").

Comment: "Candidate for closure" might sound worse than it is–basically, the idea is just that there's no point in duplicating the information in a dictionary on this site, so if a major online dictionary fully answers your question, it will be marked as not needing or allowing any new answers. New users are not expected to know all the details about how this site works, but it is a good idea to review the information and resources at that last link.

Answer (score 8):

The prevalent idea is that God is not derived from *good*:

> - Popular etymology has long derived God from good; but a comparison of the forms ... shows this to be an error. Moreover, the notion of goodness is not conspicuous in the heathen conception of deity, and in good itself the ethical sense is comparatively late. [Century Dictionary, 1902] (Etymonline)

The very interesting following  [extract from Antoly Liberman](http://blog.oup.com/2009/11/good-god-and-etymology/)  explains in detail the credible assumptions behind this assertion, and shows that it is "scientifically proved" despite many folk etymologies that tend to disagree:

> - ***Good* has transparent etymology: *gather* and *-gether* are related to it. Their root means “fit, suitable.” This circumstance is borne out by numerous cognates in and outside Germanic.**  That is “good” which has been “fixed,” “assembled,” “put together” in a proper way. ***By contrast, the origin of ‘god’ is debatable, which does not mean that we know nothing about its derivation.***

.............

> - After the conversion to Christianity, a word for “God” became necessary, and it had to belong to the masculine gender. This is indeed what happened: the singular was abstracted from the plural, and the neuter yielded to the masculine. **Whatever the etymology of *god* may be, *god* and *good* are not related.**  I should also say that reference to intuition, if intuition means an undisciplined emotion, should be avoided. Etymology is a study of word history and presupposes a professional look at the development of sounds, grammatical forms, and meaning in many languages. “Intuitively,” *deus* and *theos* are two variants of the same word, but they are not. The term folk etymology covers suggestions of the *theos-deus* and *god-good* type: the temptation to connect look-alikes is irrepressible, but, unless we choose to remain in pre-scientific etymology, it should be resisted. Although “scientific etymology” stumbles at every step, there is no need to make it limp even more by burdening it with naïve medieval hypotheses. I sincerely hope that no schism will be the result of this post.